# Mesons wavefunction symmetry

Tags: wavefunction, symmetry, standard-model, quarks, mesons

Is it possible to write the valence quark wavefunction for mesons which is overall symmetric in nature?

Because acc. to me, we can not say directly that flavor and color wavefunction is symmetric as they builds from quark and anti-quark.

They do not obey pauli exclusion principles like baryons.

Is it correct to think like that?

Comment: Basically yes; you may connect quarks and antiquarks with the C operator, and introduce G-parity, etc... but, yes, indeed, it is a nonsensical mistake to attempt to play the same generalized Pauli exclusion game you play with baryons....

Comment: okay ... so can i make wavefunction to be symmetric or antisymmetric by introducing the G-parity as G parity is +ve for pseudoscalar mesons and -ve for vector mesons?

Answer (score 0):

Basically yes; you may connect quarks and antiquarks with the C operator, and introduce G-parity, etc, but, yes, indeed, it is a nonsensical mistake to attempt to play the same generalized Pauli exclusion game you play with baryons.

Just review the [meson-building rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meson#Overview), first practicing on fermion-antifermion systems such as [ortho and para positronium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positronium), and only *then* generalizing to quarks. Meson wavefunctions factorize into space, spin, and color and flavor parts.

Make sure you can prove
$$
P=(-)^L\\
C=(-)^{L+S}\\
G=(-)^{S+L+I}.
$$
It thus follows that the *G* parity of π s is -, whilst  + for ρ s...